# Wrong output of the intrinsic function fraction() in Fortran

Tags: floating-point, fortran

I do not understand the output of FRACTION(), for example

```
write(*,*) fraction(553.334)
```

It gives me `0.5403652`.

I thought it should return `0.334`, as `553.334-floor(553.334)` does. What is wrong in my understanding?

Answer (score 8):

*Au contraire*, that value is exactly (within the limits of precision available) the right answer.  I think the error is that you have misunderstood what `fraction` does.  To paraphrase the standard (widely available online, as are many tutorials and other guides) `fraction(x)` returns the fractional part of the *model representation* of `x`.  The model representation of `x` is, on most modern computers, a number of the form `x*2^-k`. In effect the function returns the number `x` divided by the next highest power of 2, in the case of your example `553.034/1024 == 553.034*2^-10`.

As ever in computing, RTFM (Read The Fortran Manual).

Comment: Thank you.It seems I was misled by the this note http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/F90-Basics.pdf /br

Answer (score 7):

`fraction()` doesn't do what you think it does. It returns the fractional part of the *model number* (base 2). So for your example it is returning:

```
553.334/1024 = 0.5403652
```

As always, when in doubt, read [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FRACTION.html).

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround:

real(kind(1.d0)) elemental function fractional_part(x)  !Double precision
  real(kind(1.d0)),intent(IN)::x

fractional_part=x-floor(x)

end function fractional_part

If you want to use it as an overloaded module procedure, you can use your new "intrinsic" to find the fractional part of real(4), real(8), and, where supported, real(16).

Answer (score -2):

The description in the standards is "fraction(x) returns the fractional part of x."  BUT the example in the WG5 standards is fraction(3.0) -> 0.75, which is the same as set_exponent(x,0).

So, the short description in all the standards since Fortran 95 are wrong.  The actual operation is the same as set_exponent(x,0).

I think an appropriate action for WG5 for Fortran 2020 is to define "fraction(x)" as x-floor(x) for arguments of type real(4), real(8), and, if supported, real(16), and note that the muddled and confusing results are already provided by set_exponent(x,i) for i=0.  If this is already true, fix the documentation.

Comment: You should make sure to add relevant tags to your question, otherwise people with experience in that area may not find it and you're less likely to get a correct answer.

Comment: Why do you think `fraction(3.0)` should not have the value `0.75` when using the stated numeric model?  And why do you think `fraction` and `set_exponent` are the same?

Comment: francescalus - I didn't say that I thought anything.  The example in the Fortran 2008 standard uses the example that I quoted.  Sorry if I offended anyone.  My short post is based on a lot of online research on the question.  I started out using fraction(x) as x-floor(x) and was getting something else.  I think the standard has been contradictory since 1995; the intrinsic name "fraction" apparently means "mantissa" but the short description says "fractional part."

Comment: francescalus - The intrinsic "fraction(x)" apparently returns the mantissa of the floating pint number.  The intrinsic set_exponent(x,i) returns the floating point number x with its exponent, with appropriate bias, set to the integer i.  Using set_exponent(x,i) with i=0) returns the mantissa, unscaled.

Comment: What do you think "mantissa" means? It means the fractional part. A floating point number has a mantissa, exponent and sign. The standard is deliberately neutral as to what base the model uses. The standard is correct, but I can see how you misunderstood it, despite the example. What you apparently want is MOD(x,1.0). SET_EXPONENT(x,0) just returns x.

Comment: @SteveLionel --- Maybe some comments have been deleted here. Certainly something is missing: SET_EXPONENT(x,0) returns x if and only if EXPONENT( x ) returns 0.